# I want to replace missing values with 0 and 'Missing' , and in another column replace a value with another value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Any differences among these formats? What is the difference between df['column_name' ] verses df.column_name?

```
df['filed_complaint'] = df.filed_complaint.fillna(0)

df['filed_complaint'].fillna(0)

df.filed_complaint.fillna(0)
```

How about this?

```
df['department'] = df.department.fillna('Missing')
df['department'].fillna('Missing')
df.department.fillna('Missing')
```

or these?

```
df['department'] = df.department.replace('information_technology', 'IT', inplace=True)

df['department'].replace('information_technology', 'IT', inplace=True)

df.department.replace('information_technology', 'IT', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any differences among these formats? What is the difference between
> df['column_name' ] verses df.column_name?

There is no difference. However, I suggest you to use `df['column_name']` as per pandas documentation.

And regarding your two last questions, we must remember that the methods [**`pandas.Series.fillna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [**`pandas.Series.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) (like many others) return a copy of the referenced object (as you did with the following command `df['department'].fillna('Missing')`).

These two methods will not modify your original dataframe `df` but instead will return a copy of it. What does it means ? It means that any changes made to the latter will not affect the original `df`. These kind of methods can also be applied directly to your `df` if you specify the optional parameter `inplace=True` (as you did here `df.department.replace('information_technology', 'IT', inplace=True)`). But keep in mind that in this case, the operation of replacing the string `'information_technology'` is irreversible.

**Note** : No need to set the `inplace` parameter to `True` if you re-assign your column!

```
df['department'] = df.department.replace('information_technology', 'IT', inplace=True) #wrong
```